# Adding an apostrophe to entire column in Excel-VBA

Tags: vba, excel, long-integer

I've been asked to write a macro for a ~9,000 line worksheet that has numbers that are longer than Excel typically allows.  To get around this, I have to append a single quote/apostrophe to each cell prior to removing hyphens or otherwise sanitizing the data or else Excel abbreviates the numbers even when classified as Text.

Is there a way to do this other than with a FOR loop and iterating through every cell?

Comment: Run a loop through an array and do all the 'sanitizing' at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run a loop through an array and do all the 'sanitizing' at the same time.

```
dim arr as variant, i as long

with worksheets(1)

    arr = .range(.cells(2, "A"), .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup)).value2

    for i=lbound(arr, 1) to ubound(arr, 1)

        arr(i, 1) = chr(39) & replace(arr(i, 1), chr(45), vbnullstring)

    next i

    'optional text format for cells
    '.cells(2, "A").resize(ubound(arr, 1), ubound(arr, 2)).numberformat = "@"
    .cells(2, "A").resize(ubound(arr, 1), ubound(arr, 2)) = arr

end with
```

Comment: Is there a trick to declaring an array?  I'm getting an error when I use the code you supplied.  Do I need to declare the array as a string then reDim it once I get the length?

Comment: my bad, it should have been declared as a variant type.